# SED command Issue with values exceeding 9

Tags: sed, centos

I need to generate a file.sql file from a file.csv, so I use this command :

```
cat file.csv |sed "s/\(.*\),\(.*\)/insert into table(value1, value2)
values\('\1','\2'\);/g" > file.sql
```

**It works perfectly, but when the values exceed 9 (for example for \10, \11 etc...) it takes consideration of only the first number (which is \1 in this case) and ignores the rest.**

I want to know if I missed something or if there is another way to do it.

Thank you !

**EDIT :** 
The not working example :

My file.csv looks like

```
2013-04-01 04:00:52,2,37,74,40233964,3860,0,0,4878,174,3,0,0,3598,27.00,27
```

What I get

> insert into table 
>   val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12,val13,val14,val15,val16
>
> values 
>   ('2013-04-01 07:39:43',
>   2,37,74,36526530,3877,0,0,6080,
>   2013-04-01 07:39:430,2013-04-01 07:39:431,
>   2013-04-01 07:39:432,2013-04-01 07:39:433,
>   2013-04-01 07:39:434,2013-04-01 07:39:435,
>   2013-04-01 07:39:436);

After the ninth element I get the first one instead of the 10th,11th etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know `sed` has a limitation of supporting 9 back references. It might have been removed in the newer versions (though not sure). You are better off using `perl` or `awk` for this.

Here is how you'd do in `awk`:

```
$ cat csv
2013-04-01 04:00:52,2,37,74,40233964,3860,0,0,4878,174,3,0,0,3598,27.00,27

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print "insert into table values (\x27"$1"\x27",$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16 ");"}' csv
insert into table values ('2013-04-01 04:00:52',2,37,74,40233964,3860,0,0,4878,174,3,0,0,3598,27.00,27);
```

This is how you can do in `perl`:

```
$ perl -ple 's/([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)/insert into table values (\x27$1\x27,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16);/' csv
insert into table values ('2013-04-01 04:00:52',2,37,74,40233964,3860,0,0,4878,174,3,0,0,3598,27.00,27);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an `awk` script (based on @JS웃 solution):

## script.awk

```awk
#!/usr/bin/env awk
# before looping the file
BEGIN{
  FS="," # input separator
  OFS=FS # output separator
  q="\047" # single quote as a variable
}

# on each line (no pattern)
{
  printf "insert into table values ("
    print q $1 q ", "
    print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16
  print ");"
}
```

### Run with

```
awk -f script.awk file.csv
```

## One-liner

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","; q="\047" } { printf "insert into table values (" q $1 q ", " $2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13","$14","$15","$16 ");" }' file.csv
```